# Make Chat search "and" not "or"

Tags: feature-request, chat, search, chat-search

So new search for the sites defaults to "and"; adding more terms *narrows* scope. That's cool. I know/assume Chat's search wasn't overhauled and I don't expect half as much attention to be paid to Chat's search, but could we at least get Chat search to default to and? It makes it very very hard to find specific messages in chat.

Comment: Note that you can [actually use "and"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=objective+and+question&room=35).

Comment: @TimStone huh, I tried explicitly using or on normal search and it didn't work, I assumed chat ignored it as well. Still, I think implicit and makes more sense

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. Also, for extra fun, you can break chat's search by only searching for `and` or `or`.

Comment: This question is non-nonsensical.  You say that it defaults to "and", but that you want it to change to default to "and". It was edited, but even originally, it did not make sense: Originally, the title stated that you want it to be made '"and" not "or"', but the text stated that you wanted chat search to be "or". So, even the original did not make sense (was self contradictory). Please [edit] to indicate that it is one way and you want it changed to being some other way.